# Как перейти на другое activity через нажатие CardView?

Tags: java, android-studio, cardview

Всем привет ! Хочу перейти на другое активити через нажатие элемента CardView.
На одном активити я создал 3 cardview без использования RecyclerView, потому что на этой активити мне нужны всего лишь 3 кнопки.
Я создавал кнопку с айдишкой карточки, только приложение вылетало. Что делать?

Вот джава код

```
public class CpuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button myArduino;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_cpu);
myArduino = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cv1);
myArduino.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
Intent intentLoadArduinoActivity = new Intent(CpuActivity.this, 
ArduinoActivity.class);
startActivity(intentLoadArduinoActivity);
}
});
}
}
```

вот хмл код

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
 android:id="@+id/cv1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="16dp">

<ImageView
android:layout_width="100sp"
android:layout_height="100sp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/arduino"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="50sp"
                android:text="Arduino"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                android:layout_below="@+id/person_age"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="11dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/person_age"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="100sp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/vex"
                android:id="@+id/imageView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/person_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="60sp"
                android:text="VEX"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="47dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/person_age"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="100sp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/legoev3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="60sp"
                android:text="LEGO"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                android:layout_below="@+id/person_age"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="34dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/person_age"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo" />







 </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Не забывайте прикладывать логи ошибки и точную строку их возникновения. В данном случая и без них можно, но в большинстве остальных вы не получите ответа без этой информации

Answer (score 0):

У вас `ClassCastException`. В разметке у вас `CardView`, а вы пытаетесь его скастовать к `Button`.

Вам надо указывать в Java коде тот же класс, который используется в разметке. Т.е. вместо

```
Button myArduino;
myArduino = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cv1);
```

Должно быть

```
CardView myArduino;
myArduino = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cv1);
```

Answer (score 0):

у тебя R.id.cv1 привязано к CardView, а не кнопке.
попробуй сделать так:

```
CardView myArduino = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cv1);
myArduino.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
Intent intentLoadArduinoActivity = new Intent(CpuActivity.this, 
ArduinoActivity.class);
startActivity(intentLoadArduinoActivity);
}
});
```